# Derive canonical momentum in electromagnetic field without knowledge of Lagrangian and Hamiltonian mechanics

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, momentum, hamiltonian, education

One of my friend is studying quantum mechanics and he asks me a lot.
This time, he asked me about the momentum expression in Hamiltonian of charged particle in electromagnetic field.

$$H = \frac{1}{2m} (\vec p - q\vec A)^2 +q\varphi.$$

Lots of explanation about canonical momentum with vector potential starts with Lagrangian or velocity dependent potential. I think those explanation is way too much for him.

Is there better way to explain the canonical momentum for charged particle which can be understood without knowledge of Lagrangian?

FYI, here are some backgrounds of his state:

- He understands that $q\varphi$ is the potential energy of charged particle.
- He does not understand why the momentum term contains vector potential.
- He knows that the vector potential is defined by $\vec B = \vec \nabla \times \vec A$ and a little of gauge transform from electromagnetism.
- He does not understand Lagrangian and canonical momentum.

For him, Hamiltonian is just mechanical energy 
$$\frac{1}{2}m\vec{v}^2 +q\varphi$$ 
which is weirdly expressed with  what-so-called operator in quantum mechanics. He barely knows analytical mechanics. I think lots of students who start to learn quantum mechanics from wave mechanics recognize Hamiltonian in same way.

Comment: Does he know Hamilton's equations?

Comment: @Qmechanic I don't think so. He does not know any of Lagrangian/Lagrange-Euler eq./Hamilton's eq./canonical transform.

Comment: If he doesn't know about these equations then why he asks?

Comment: If he doesn’t know Hamiltonian mechanics, then of course he will be confused by the _Hamiltonian_ in QM. The two are named similarly for a reason.

Comment: The amount of analytical mechanics he _knows_ doesn't matter nearly as much as the amount of analytical mechanics he _is willing to learn_ to satisfy his curiosity. Indeed, this could be a great motivator to introduce some of those topics to him!